# Error with p:selectOneMenu in Primefaces 3.4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I recently updated Primefaces from 3.4 to 3.4.2 and now I have problems on some pages where there is `p:selectOneMenu` component. I see error in JavaScript console which says: `TypeError: e.offset(...) is undefined`. This error is logged immediately on page loading.

Does anyone know what is a problem?

Comment: Sound like a jQuery version clash. Are you manually including a `jquery.js` file in every page for some reason instead of relying on the one already provided by PrimeFaces itself? PrimeFaces updates the version of the builtin jQuery library with almost every release. The solution would obviously be to stop manually including jQuery and just use the PrimeFaces provided one.

Comment: No, a just use the default jQuery provided. I saw that they changed jQuery version in 3.4.2, so I tried with Primefaces 3.4.1, and it works fine. JavaScript error is in primefaces.js file, line 1. Following the stack in Javascript I saw that top level function called is: `PrimeFaces.cw('SelectOneMenu','widget_aswdatatable_detaljSubview_editForm_paket',{id:'aswdatatable:detaljSubview:editForm:paket',effect:'fade'});}`

Comment: I'm using 3.4.2 as well and unable to reproduce your problem. I'd still suspect some bad jQuery-related JS file causing the trouble. Have you investigated the `<script>` references in the obtained HTML output and/or the HTTP traffic, just to be sure?

Comment: OK. I found why is this happening, but still don't know is this a bug or I'm just not using this on right way. I have one composite component with datatable and few dialogs which shows details of entries. In composite component I defined facet detailForm, and I rendered that facet in every dialog. Of course, I encapsulated every `cc:renderFacet` in different `f:subview`. Is this OK, and if it is not what I should do? When I leave just one `cc:renderFacet` it works fine.

Comment: Finally, the problem happens when I render same facet multiple times in composite component. Primefaces generates the same `widgetVar` for all `selectOneMenu` elements. I find out this by inspecting generated HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after a lot of time a finally figure out what's happening. In Primefaces 3.4.2 behavior of `p:selectOneMenu` is changed little bit, in that way that **change** event is fired immediately after page is loaded. This problem is manifesting when we have completely empty `p:selectOneMenu`, which means `value` of `f:selectItems` is null, and there is no `f:selectItem` for empty option. In that case we can see error `TypeError: e.offset(...) is undefined` in console and javascript is from that point useless, and nothing works any more. For now it has to be empty `f:selectItem`, or at least one element in `f:selectItems`.

Comment: Nice workaround. Have you filed or found an issue at Primefaces Bug Tracker? If yes kindly share here.

Comment: Actually not. Maybe event this bug is fixed in 3.5 I really don't know. But in fact that is probably more problem in jQuery than in Primefaces.